# Can I train a Tensorflow keras model with complex input/output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a very simple model which only have one convolution layer.

```
 def kernel_model(filters=1, kernel_size=3):
    input_layer = Input(shape=(250,1))
    conv_layer = Conv1D(filters=filters,kernel_size=kernel_size,padding='same',use_bias = False)(input_layer)
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer,output=conv_layer)
    return model
```

But the input(X), prediction output(y_pred) and true_output(y_true) are all complex number. When I call the function `model.fit(X,y_true)`

There is the error 
`TypeError: Gradients of complex tensors must set grad_ys (y.dtype = tf.complex64)`

Does that means I have to write the back-propagation by hand?
What should I do to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: Out of couriosity, what is the Loss function used (I assume it is real?), and what scenario does the complex numbers support?

Comment: Oh, I have define the function as below:


```def mse_error(y_true,y_pred): 
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred,tf.complex64)
    y_true = K.cast(y_true,tf.complex64)
    error = K.cast(K.mean(K.square(y_pred_propgation - y_true)),tf.complex64)
    return error ```

Comment: You can't minimize an error (loss) function that is complex. Complex numbers do not have an ordering. I think you need a real loss, e.g. ||.||^2

Comment: I change the function to be :
`K.mean(K.square(K.abs(y_true-y_pred)))`
Then the model can be trained!  I will check whether the prediction result is right or not. Thanks for help @MartinThøgersen. Really helps a lot!

Comment: Cool. Please mark my answer as an answer.

Comment: Could you provide a [mrve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this implementation please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your DNN needs to mininimize the Loss-function through back-propagation. To minimize something, it naturally needs to have an ordering. Complex numbers are not ordered, while Reals are.
So you generally need a loss function `L: Complex -> Reals`

Change your *complex-valued* loss function from simple square:

```
error = K.cast(K.mean(K.square(y_pred_propgation - y_true)),tf.complex64)
```

to a *real-valued* magnitude ||.||^2 of the complex number:

```
error = K.mean(K.square(K.abs(y_true-y_pred)))
```